# Capture arguments of onclick() javascript call using Selenium Java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, javascript, qa-developer

I am writing a selenium script in Java to capture the arguments passed in JavaScript onclick() call/method. Attached is the image in which method/function name is highlighted. [image]

Now, In this method there are some arguments/parameters which i want to capture same as we capture any css_Selector. I am unable to do this. Is there any method or way to do this task? In the Below attached image, i want to capture arguments such as "content_ids", "content_type", "value", "currency" and "content_name".
Kindly suggest me solution.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

see [how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-script-tag-in-selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497607/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-script-tag-in-selenium)

`element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");` could help you here

Comment: i have tried element.GetAttribute("innerHTML"); but it captures all the response within the script tag.
i want to capture content/variables individually

Comment: There is no other way, you need to get the `String`, then obtain the `JSON`, then parse the `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if you really want to test the implementation details of a JavaScript method via an end-to-end testing framework. Probably the method can be tested on a different level in the test pyramid. For end-to-end tests build checks for the actual user behavior, not the implementation.